# Why does fieldset does not work in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

someone recommend me to use the fieldset but it didn't work,

here is the code

```
.block{
 display: inline-block;
 border: 2px solid white;
 }
.title2{
 color: white;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 text-align: center;
}

<fieldset class="block">
        <legend class="title2">
                Services
        </legend>
 </fieldset>
```

it show like this

[image]

I want is like this

[image]

here is the underline

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

Because your theme can override your `fieldset` style, you can just use `!important` to fix.

```css
fieldset.block {
    font-family: sans-serif!important;
    border: 5px solid #1F497D!important;
    background: #eee!important;
    border-radius: 5px!important;
    padding: 15px!important;
}
fieldset.block legend.title2 {
    background: #1F497D!important;
    color: #fff!important;
    padding: 5px 10px!important;
    font-size: 32px!important;
    border-radius: 5px!important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #ddd!important;
    margin-left: 20px!important;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="block">
  <legend class="title2">Services</legend>
  <p>Some text.</p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: still got an underline under the text

Comment: how to share it to the comment?